# how to get the functionality of SoapUI in to an Android project

Tags: java, android, soap, wsdl, soapui

i am developing a project where i need to read a wsdl and convert it to a soap request. using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) i can achieve what i need and also there is another [eclipse plugin](http://wscep.sourceforge.net/createrequest.html) but they all are tools kind of IDEs but i need that same functionality to be integrated into my Android project can anybody help me?

Thanks !!!

Comment: So you want to generate the proxy classes at runtime?  How do you hope to compile them?

Answer (score 1):

SoapUI is a complex and mature application.  If you want the same functionality, there are some libraries around for java to help with that, but you'll have to write it.